# Sending contact form data using Ajax/jQuery/PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I had a functioning contact form, but decided to try learn a little Ajax to improve usability and error checking. I'm using code from this [**example**](http://www.dzyngiri.com/slick-contact-form-using-jquery-php) which I've adapted slightly to accommodate the new .ajaxComplete() guidelines.

I've zero idea why this isn't working, but I'll provide both my form, ajax request and working example in the hope someone can help:

[**My website**](http://investmentproperty.uk.com/contact/)

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#get-contact-form").submit(function() {

    var str = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "contact-process.php",
            data: str,
            success: function(msg) {

                $(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings) {

                if (msg == 'OK') {

                    result = '<div class="notification_ok">Your message has been sent Succesfully. Thank you!!!</div>';
                    $("#fields").hide();

                }
                else
                {

                    result = msg;

                }

                $("#note").hide();
                $("#note").html(result).slideDown("slow");
                $("#note").html(result);

                });

            }

        });

    return false;

    });

});
```

**PHP** (Please note I've removed all validation here to make it easier to follow)

```
$title     = $_POST["Form"]["title"];
$forename  = trim($_POST["Form"]["forename"]);
$surname   = trim($_POST["Form"]["surname"]);
$telephone = trim($_POST["Form"]["telephone"]);
$email     = trim($_POST["Form"]["email"]);
$message   = trim($_POST["Form"]["message"]);

$name = $title . " " . $forename . " " . $surname;

require_once("inc/PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$email_body = "";
$email_body = $email_body . "<h1 class='heading'><strong>Name:</strong></h1><br />" . $name . "<br />";
$email_body = $email_body . "<h1 class='heading'><strong>Telephone Number:</strong></h1><br />" . $telephone . "<br />";
$email_body = $email_body . "<h1 class='heading'><strong>Email:</strong></h1><br />" . $email . "<br />";
$email_body = $email_body . "<h1 class='heading'><strong>Message:</strong></h1><br />" . $message;

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->Username = "****";
$mail->Password = "****";

$mail->SetFrom($email, $name);
$address = "*******";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "*****");
$mail->Subject = "Email Subject | " . $name;
$mail->MsgHTML($email_body);
```

**HTML**

```
<form class="cf form-contact" id="get-contact-form" action="javascript:alert('success!');" >
    <div id="note"></div>
    <div id="fields">
        <div class="row grid-full">
            <label for="title">Title</label>
            <select name="Form[title]" id="title">
                <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
                <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
                <option value="Ms">Ms</option>
                <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
                <option value="Dr">Dr</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-2">
            <label for="forname">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="Form[forename]" id="forename" />
            <label for="surname">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="Form[surname]" id="surname" />
        </div>
        <div class="grid-2">
            <label for="telephone">Telephone</label>
            <input type="text" name="Form[telephone]" id="telephone" />
            <label for="email">Email Address</label>
            <input type="text" name="Form[email]" id="email" />
        </div>
        <div class="row grid-4" style="display: none;">
            <label for="address">Address</label>
            <input type="text" name="Form[address]" id="address" />
            <p>Please leave this field blank.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="row grid-4">
            <label for="message">Comments</label>
            <textarea rows="12" name="Form[message]" id="message"></textarea>
            <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Where is your server side script???, I can see in the firebug that the ajax is working fine, your server side script is the problem

Comment: Please see edit....I've removed all validation to make it easier to follow

Comment: As far as I can see it's working just fine, but the server isn't returning any content, so logically you won't see anything appear in the message box.

Comment: @EmilioGort the code currently live is also clear of validation whilst I try find the issue!

Comment: comment the email part in your php and do a print_r($_POST) to see how are receiving the data

Comment: @EmilioGort :) good call, http://novicecoder.co.uk/priestley/contact.php the Ajax is working correctly

Comment: Add this to the end of your php and remove the print_r, `if(!$mail->send()) {
   echo 'Message could not be sent.';
   echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}` , to see what is the error

Comment: @EmilioGort no error, I am now receiving an email!!! Thank you, if you answer I'll mark as correct. One issue does still remain, the content within div#fields is not hiding and there isn't the success message?

Comment: let me check taht part

Comment: What you want to do with this `if (msg == 'OK') {

                    result = '<div class="notification_ok">Your message has been sent Succesfully. Thank you!!!</div>';
                    $("#fields").hide();

                }
                else
                {

                    result = msg;

                }

                $("#note").hide();
                $("#note").html(result).slideDown("slow");
                $("#note").html(result);`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38514/discussion-between-emilio-gort-and-sam-holguin)

Comment: click in the chat link

Comment: @EmilioGort On success I'm aiming to hide the contact form and display a success message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer#a-simple-example) you are missing this lines in your php

```
if(!$mail->send()) {
   echo 'Message could not be sent.';
   echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}else{
   echo 'ok';
}
```